# PHP does not insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert into mysql but it giving me an error, here my code :

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO property( Pname, P_Price,P_Desc,P_City, P_Size,P_Rooms, P_garage, P_Address, P_Long, P_Lat, P_Sold, Provinces_idProvinces)
    VALUES('http://10.0.2.2/images/pic3.jpg',98000,'beautifull house','Durban','7m',1,2,'L-377 Umlazi','30.863226','-29.971518',0,'1'");

 if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = $result ;

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        echo $response["success"];

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

 mysql_close();
```

And it returning the message **"Oop! An error occured**" Which i dont get how it happen

and my mysql

```
CREATE TABLE property (
  idProperty int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Pname varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  P_Price double DEFAULT NULL,
  P_Desc varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  P_City varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  P_Siz varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  P_Rooms varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  P_garage int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  P_Address varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  P_Long float (10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  P_Lat float (10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  P_Sold tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  Provinces_idProvinces int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idProperty),
  KEY fk_Property_Provinces (Provinces_idProvinces),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Property_Provinces FOREIGN KEY (Provinces_idProvinces) REFERENCES provinces (idProvinces) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Comment: Try echoing out your query and running it straight in the database; you'll get a much more useful error message then.

Comment: Do what andrewsi and skowron-line said, like this: `$response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred: " . mysql_error();` - and let us know what is the real error message.

Comment: if my running into my database it inserting, but now i want it to insert using PHP

Comment: Are you creating a connection with `mysql_connect` and selecting a database with `mysql_select_db` before using `mysql_query`, right?!

Comment: yes I'm sure i did that Bruni

Comment: Then have you added the code that @J.Bruni suggested? If you can see the error you're getting from the database, you'll see what's wrong with your SQL.

Comment: @andrewsi I just told him, it running perfect in my database

Comment: no, it is not running perfect in your database - you forgot the parenthesis, as David found out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you didn't close out the Values with an end parentheses.

```
$result = mysql_query(
"INSERT INTO property( Pname, P_Price,P_Desc,P_City, P_Size,P_Rooms, P_garage, P_Address, P_Long, P_Lat, P_Sold, Provinces_idProvinces)
VALUES('http://10.0.2.2/images/pic3.jpg',98000,'beautifull house','Durban','7m',1,2,'L-377 Umlazi','30.863226','-29.971518',0,'1')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Provinces_idProvinces as '1' which is a string, not an int as your table describes.

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO property( Pname, P_Price,P_Desc,P_City, P_Size,P_Rooms, P_garage, P_Address, P_Long, P_Lat, P_Sold, Provinces_idProvinces)
    VALUES('http://10.0.2.2/images/pic3.jpg',98000,'beautifull house','Durban','7m',1,2,'L-377 Umlazi','30.863226','-29.971518',0,1)");
```

Comment: He removed the quotes around the last value (the 1 for Provinces_idProvinces)

Comment: You have the column Provinces_idProvinces int(11) NOT NULL but are inserting the value '1' which is a string. Inserting it without the quotes should do the trick.

Comment: No, there is no problem enclosing a numeric value with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Three issues:

1. You have P_Siz instead of P_Size in your mysql create table schema
2. You are missing the trailing ) after your values statement
3. Remove the single quotes after Provinces_idProvinces

I've corrected the issues in this **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fae55/1)** (removed foreign key association)