# Error when inserting

Tags: php, mysql

I need to insert into database, but it giving me errors , I just saw silimar example here but mine is not working please tell me what is the problem :

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","****","****");
if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());
 }
mysql_select_db("properties", $con);

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO property( Pname, P_Price,P_Desc,P_City, P_Size,P_Rooms, P_garage, P_Address, P_Long, P_Lat,  Provinces_idProvinces)
    VALUES
        ('$_POST[Pname]','$_POST[P_Price]','$_POST[P_Price]','$_POST[P_Desc]','$_POST[P_City]','$_POST[P_Size]','$_POST[P_Rooms]','$_POST[P_garage]','$_POST[P_Address]','$_POST[P_Long]','$_POST[P_Lat]','$_POST[Provinces_idProvinces]')");   

 if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = $result ;

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        echo $response["success"];

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

 mysql_close();

?>
```

I need to but url like this : localhost/php/add.php , And it must display {"success":1,"message":true} , but it does not please help me

Comment: like this one : "success":0,"message":Oops! An error occurred

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Is that your actual database password?

Comment: Your code is also **extermely vulnerable to *SQL Injection*** Please do implement what I have written in the comment above to negate it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that all sites on StackExchange network are public, meaning anything you place here would be shown to to world wide web. Please refrain from posting any passwords, credit card numbers, access tokens, database credentials, or any other personal information of you or anyone else.

Comment: For debugging purposes, you should seriously look into changing $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred."; to $response["message"] = mysql_error();

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO property( Pname, P_Price,P_Desc,P_City, P_Size,P_Rooms, P_garage, P_Address, P_Long, P_Lat,  Provinces_idProvinces)
    VALUES
        ('$_POST[Pname]','$_POST[P_Price]','$_POST[P_Desc]','$_POST[P_City]','$_POST[P_Size]','$_POST[P_Rooms]','$_POST[P_garage]','$_POST[P_Address]','$_POST[P_Long]','$_POST[P_Lat]','$_POST[Provinces_idProvinces]')");
```

you have ,'$_POST[P_Price]', repeated twice.

Comment: It still giving me same problem

Answer (score 0):

If this is related to your other question: [PHP does not insert into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190839/php-does-not-insert-into-mysql/11191456#11191456)

Three issues:

1. You have P_Siz instead of P_Size in your mysql create table schema
2. All non-string fields should not have single quotes surrounding them. This is telling MySQL to cast them as strings. If the field in an int field, it will fail to insert.

I've corrected the issues in this **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fae55/1)** (removed foreign key association)

Try the following INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO property( Pname, P_Price,P_Desc,P_City, P_Size,P_Rooms, P_garage, P_Address, P_Long, P_Lat,  Provinces_idProvinces)
VALUES ('$_POST[Pname]',$_POST[P_Price],'$_POST[P_Desc]','$_POST[P_City]','$_POST[P_Size]','$_POST[P_Rooms]',$_POST[P_garage],'$_POST[P_Address]',$_POST[P_Long],$_POST[P_Lat],$_POST[Provinces_idProvinces])");
```

Comment: It giving me same error :0{"success":0,"message":"Oops! An error occurred."} which I need a positive result

Comment: Seriously, change `$response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";` to `$response["message"] = mysql_error();`

Comment: I'm getting this error : 0{"success":0,"message":"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''','','','',,'',,,)' at line 4"}

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care about names and number of columns and names and number of corresponding values in sql statement.